# How to fix the textarea in right side in Spotfire

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I have generated a dynamic report in which when user clicks on a Generate Button, every time a new reports gets add on the page. My problem is - I have put the Button in the text area and wants to fix the text area in the right side of the page.

When user clicks on this button, new report generates and the textarea position is getting change.
I want to fix the textarea.

Can anyone suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Could you upload a dxp file for reference ?

Answer (score 2):

There is kind of a hack for this, but not sure if this will help. Basically you take the URL that runs that TextArea and place it on the collaboration panel of that page. (Interestingly you can drive the button from a web-browsers since Spotfire architecture is based on TCP/IP)

1. Add this html code in your textarea:

   ```
   <div id='textAreaUrl'>--url should appear here--</div>
   ```
2. Add this javascript:

   ```
   $('#textAreaUrl').text(top.location)
   ```

Once you know what the url for that TextArea is, you can use it on your collaboration panel and remove the extra html and javascript needed to reveal such.

Comment: creative solution! I never considered using the collab panel as a way to add functionality to controls.